# Replace word between two sets of brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
"You have just received {{PowerUpName}} from {{PlayerName}}"
```

I then receive a set of parameters (in JSON format):

```
{"PowerUpName":"Super Boost","PlayerName":"John"}
```

I'm trying to work out how I replace the words within double brackets i.e. {{PowerUpName}} with a parameter. I guess I need to use regex but I have no idea what the expression should be. I'm coding in C# by the way (and can't use LINQ).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `@"(?<=\{\{).*?(?=\}\})"` matches the text within braces. Seems like you need to use dictionary like function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace any words inside `{{` and `}}` symbols, you do not need LINQ:

```
// Input string
string str = "You have just received {{PowerUpName}} from {{PlayerName}}";
// Initializing sample dictionary object
var obj = new Dictionary<string,string>();
// Filling it out
obj.Add("PowerUpName", "Super Boost");
obj.Add("PlayerName", "John");
// Replacing the values with those in the dictionary
string output = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=\\{\\{)(.*?)(?=\\}\\})", match => obj[match.Groups[1].Value]);
// Display result
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Result:

```
You have just received {{Super Boost}} from {{John}}
```

Comment: Hi stribizhev, I should have been more specific in my question. I need the regex to replace the double brackets too. I.e. "You have just received {{PowerUpName}} from {{PlayerName}}", would become "You have just received SuperBoost from John.

Comment: What about removing the curly braces right after a replacement is done? E.g. `output = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=\\{\\{)(.*?)(?=\\}\\})", match => obj[match.Groups[1].Value]).Replace("{{", string.Empty).Replace("}}", string.Empty);`. It is not possible to exclude them since they are not present in the dictionary keys. If you can, just add them to the keys, then, you won't have this issue. Have a look at http://goo.gl/sk9jRT.

Answer (score 2):

If the string "You have just received `{{PowerUpName}}` from `{{PlayerName}}`" is always the same you don't need `regex`.
You can simply use the `String.Replace` method for every parameter from `JSON`.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified the words between the brackets will change. There will always be an expected parameter to replace the word though.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the brackets are correctly matched and there are no nested brackets, you can do this

```
var obj = {"PowerUpName":"Super Boost","PlayerName":"John"};
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\{\{.*?(?=\}\})", delegate(match){
    return obj[match];    
});
```